# Checkbox .change() event not firing inside of jQuery .when()

Tags: jquery

I have two ajax functions that fetch JSON objects using .getJSON and then build a table and drop-down menu using the contents of those objects.  This much is working fine.  Now I'm attempting to attach an event to each of the checkboxes located in the first column of the table.  Naturally I want this to happen after the ajax calls are done.  JQuery's .when() function seems like a good solution in that it will wait until both ajax functions are complete.  Below is my code.  I'm not sure what I did wrong.  For some reason the alert inside of the .when function does not fire.  Can someone point out what I've done wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.when(createSpotsTable(), createMarketDropDown(1))
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').change(
       alert("Hello world!")
    );
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code is missing some things. For example you are not registering any callback to the object returned by `$.when`. That means, no code will be executed when the Ajax calls finish. Instead, the `$('input:checkbox').click(...)` will be executed immediately.
Maybe you thought `$.when` is blocking the execution, but it is not. Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Furthermore, you are assigning the *return value* of `alert` as event handler, but you have to pass a *function* to `.change`.

I think what you want is:

```
$.when(createSpotsTable(), createMarketDropDown(1)).done(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
       alert("Hello world!")
    });
});
```

But you don't have to use `$.when`, you can just make use of event delegation:

```
createSpotsTable();
createMarketDropDown(1);

$(document).on('change','input:checkbox', function () {
    alert("Hello world!")
});
```

Comment: Thanks Felix.  That clarified several things for me.  However, with the second approach my Javascript console is showing the following "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'". It refers to line 19 in jquery.js.  Any thoughts on what the issue could be?

Comment: @hughesdan: You are probably not using the latest version of jQuery ;) (1.7.1)

Comment: Yep that was indeed the problem.  Thank you! +1 for answering the question within the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use live event,

```
jQuery.getJSON('xyz.com',function(){
  $('input:checkbox').live('click',function () {
   // Do you processing.
  }) 
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like the live event is deprecated though. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks to take that to my notice.

As you may be aware, use 'on'.

Comment: Why would you use `live` inside the callback? The advantage of `live` is that you can register the event handler any time. So you should do it before you make the Ajax call.